# Storing access token from Identity Server in NET Core web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have net core web application targeting an API and authenticating with Identity Server(also as web application). Because application is web server based, I have problem with storing access token from Identity Server which application needs in every request(in Header) in order to communicate with API. An ideal flow is: user launchs application and being prompt to enter his phone number(in order to get OTP code and authenticate), when submits phone number Identity Server with some external providers sends OTP code to user and now user is being prompt to enter OTP code. After successuflly submits OTP code, Identity Server verifies it and give access token to client. And this is point where problem starts.

First I tried to store access token with singleton that after otp validation stores(in some dictionary) access token related with phone number as key. But, problem is because application is webserver based and in production on server it is not mandatory that each user will have his application instance running on server, so singleton is useless beacese most likely we have at example 3-4 application running for 20 users and in that situation more than one users uses same singleton!
Then I googled and found that best option is to store access token or some realted keys for that token in browser session or document cookie. So now application is working in way that after OTP code validation user's phone number and access token stores in Dictionary collection(now more users use same collection, beacuse singleton is useless for this) where key is phone number and access token is value, then  javascript triggers and set user phone number in cookie(in each request) and now when creating Bearer header I simply read cookie from current reqeust and with that phone number i take access token from collection. 
So this solution is very bad because everything(after logging in) that you need to get access token is to modify phone number in cookie and if you are lucky and match some existing number in collection you will get access token and easily get access to API.

Down below is method that is being called in each request in order to get access token from collection where access token with phone number was put after otp validation.

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
            string phoneNumber = GetUserPhoneNumber();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(phoneNumber));

            if (_usersTokenStore == null || _usersTokenStore.Count == 0)
                throw new NotImplementedException(nameof(_usersTokenStore));

            var refSingleUser = new SingleUserTokenStore();
            bool userHaveAccessToken = _usersTokenStore.TryGetValue(phoneNumber, out refSingleUser);

            if (!userHaveAccessToken)
                throw new Exception($"User with {phoneNumber} not authorized.");

            if (refSingleUser.IsTimeToRefreshToken)
               return await RefreshAndGetAccessToken();

            return refSingleUser.AccessToken;
        }


private string GetUserPhoneNumber()
        {
            if (_httpContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(_httpContext));

            var phoneNumberCookie = _httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Where(c => c.Key == "phone_number").FirstOrDefault();

            if (phoneNumberCookie.Value == null || phoneNumberCookie.Key == null)
                return null;

            return phoneNumberCookie.Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're doing here. If this is a web application (i.e. the user is presented with HTML views that they navigate between in a web browser), then you need to employ cookie authentication. There is no way for the user of a web browser to pass an `Authorization` header with each request. Cookie auth is the only way to persist authentication in a web browser.

If this is an API, then it is on the *client* to store the access token and submit it along with each request via the `Authorization` header.

In either case, you should not persist the auth token server-side. That is not the responsibility of the server.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for reply! In short, application is some kind of online store where users can buy coupons and spent them in merchant's stores.

Comment: Then you need cookie auth.

Comment: If I need to employ cookie authentication do I need to request from user cookie enabling, otherwise it won't work? Beacuse we don't want to force users to use cookies.

Comment: You have no choice. Auth requires cookies. Unfortunately, the media and uninformed and ignorant politicians have made cookies out to be some sinister thing that should be avoided. HTTP is a stateless protocol and cookies are what are used to fake state. No cookies, no state. Plain and simple. For GDPR compliance, you must inform the user of your cookie usage, but ultimately, if they opt out, they don't get to login. That's just how it works.

Comment: I got it. I thought there is some way to avoid cookie enabling but it is clear now that we should use them. Thanks again Chris, best regards!

Comment: And just to answer you for authroization header on each request, we use NSwag for generating ApiClient classes and there is method called PrepareRequest that can be overrided, and this method is being called before every API request from client app. We simply overrieded it and implemented our logic for adding custom authroization header with bearer token.

Comment: Your web app wouldn't use a user auth token to communicate with your API, typically. You'd simply use client credentials to authorize the web app's ability to use the API, in general, and this token is what would be sent to the API, regardless of the particular user. The only time you'd utilize an actual user auth token, is if your interacting with an API on behalf of a user, and that usually is only when it's actually a third-party API. For example, the Facebook API supports both client credentials and user auth. You'd use the former for general request...

Comment: and the latter only when you need to do something *as* the user, such as post on their wall.

Comment: What is difference between user and client access token? If I understand you, you say that I was using client access token as user access token beacuse I put on token key that is related with specific user and that is what turns client into user token? And pupropse of access token is to grant access to client, not to user so this is why is bad idea to store token with key realted to user, but insted of that right thing is to use cookie authentication and allow cookie to use access token as client app token? Right?